# Delete Expired Access Tokens

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

Is there any way to delete all expired access tokens from database?

Currently I am using Django-oauth2 toolkit.

At present there is no mechanism is provided by oauth2 for deletion of expired Access Tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run from django shell or create custom management command that executes

```
from provider.oauth2.models import AccessToken
AccessToken.objects.filter(expires__lt=datetime.now()).delete()
```